# Python ASCII-Art Text Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

```
               _____    _____   _____   _____              _____    _______
      /\      / ____|  / ____| |_   _| |_   _|     /\     |  __ \  |__   __|
     /  \    | (___   | |        | |     | |      /  \    | |__) |    | |
    / /\ \    \___ \  | |        | |     | |     / /\ \   |  _  /     | |
   / ____ \   ____) | | |____   _| |_   _| |_   / ____ \  | | \ \     | |
  /_/    \_\ |_____/   \_____| |_____| |_____| /_/    \_\ |_|  \_\    |_|
```

---

As a part of a console utilities module that I'm building, the central function (after which the module is named) is a function that generates ASCII art representation of given text.

Any comments or suggestions for improvement will be great!

```
default_conf = open('C://Programs//Python35//Lib//asciiart.txt').read()

...

def asciiart (text, conf=default_conf):
    """Produces an ascii art representation of text using the conf data"""

    if isinstance(conf, str): conf = conf.split('\n')

    height, key, data = int(conf[0]), conf[1], conf[2:]
    figures = dict(map(lambda x: (x, data[key.index(x) * height : key.index(x) * height + height]), key))
    art = '\n'.join(['\n'.join([' '.join([figures[x][i] for x in t.lower() if x in figures]) for i in range(height)]) for t in text.split('\n')])

    return art
```

Here is a demo:

```
>>> import asciiart
>>> print(asciiart.asciiart('code-review'))
  _____    ____    _____    ______          _____    ______  __      __  _____   ______  __          __
 / ____|  / __ \  |  __ \  |  ____|        |  __ \  |  ____| \ \    / / |_   _| |  ____| \ \        / /
| |      | |  | | | |  | | | |__     ____  | |__) | | |__     \ \  / /    | |   | |__     \ \  /\  / /
| |      | |  | | | |  | | |  __|   |____| |  _  /  |  __|     \ \/ /     | |   |  __|     \ \/  \/ /
| |____  | |__| | | |__| | | |____         | | \ \  | |____     \  /     _| |_  | |____     \  /\  /
 \_____|  \____/  |_____/  |______|        |_|  \_\ |______|     \/     |_____| |______|     \/  \/
```

---

The configuration file format is as follows:

- First line: the `height` of every character in the configuration file (number of lines).
- Second line: the `key`. A string containing the letters in the order they appear in the configuration file.
- Next `height * len(key)` lines: the text representation of the characters.

The full configuration file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/wWpx8d7b) (covers most of the printable ASCII characters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Style

You’ve already been told that by [@alexwlchan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144816/84718) in your previous question but: "whitespace is cheap" and it improves readability a lot. Compare your code to:

```
def asciiart(text, conf=default_conf):
    """Produces an ascii art representation of text using the conf data"""
    if isinstance(conf, str):
        conf = conf.split('\n')

    height, key, data = int(conf[0]), conf[1], conf[2:]
    figures = dict(map(
        lambda x: (x, data[key.index(x) * height: (key.index(x) + 1) * height]),
        key))
    art = '\n'.join([
        '\n'.join([
            ' '.join([figures[x][i] for x in t.lower() if x in figures])
            for i in range(height)])
        for t in text.split('\n')])
    return art
```

Again, you should also consider using generator expressions rather than list-comprehensions to feed into your `join` calls: turn those square brackets into parenthesis.

## Handling font configuration

First of, when reading the file, you should remember to close it:

```
with open('C://Programs//Python35//Lib//asciiart.txt') as configuration_file:
    default_conf = configuration_file.read()
```

You may also want to name the resulting string `DEFAULT_CONF` as it is a constant.

Second, why parse this string at each call of `asciiart`? You should provide a function that will do the parsing and `asciiart` will only be responsible of using the parsed configuration:

```
ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION = {}


def parse_ascii_art_configuration(filename='C://Programs//Python35//Lib//asciiart.txt'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        conf = f.read().split('\n')
    height, key, data = int(conf[0]), conf[1], conf[2:]
    figures = dict(map(
        lambda x: (x, data[key.index(x) * height: (key.index(x) + 1) * height]),
        key))
    ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION.update(figures)


def asciiart(text):
    if not ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION:
        parse_ascii_art_configuration()

    art = '\n'.join(
        '\n'.join(
            ' '.join(ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION[x][i]
                     for x in t.lower() if x in ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION)
            for i in range(height))
        for t in text.split('\n'))
    return art
```

The advantage being:

1. You give your users direct access to the underlying `ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION` that they can populate the way they want if need be;
2. You give your users an easy way to provide their own configuration filepaths;
3. You parse the configuration only once.

Obviously, this version wont work since `asciiart` does not have access to `height` any more. Time to bring our old friend `zip` (or `itertools.zip_longest`) back:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def asciiart(text):
    if not ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION:
        parse_ascii_art_configuration()

    art = '\n'.join(
        '\n'.join(
            ' '.join(row)
            for row in zip_longest(
                (ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION[x]
                 for x in t.lower() if x in ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION),
                fillvalue=''))
        for t in text.split('\n'))
    return art
```

## Better iterations

Now that we have a better API, let's focus a bit more on the code:

- iteration over a file can be made using either the "reading" API or the iterator one, this can help better handle the separation of each part:

  ```
  with open(filename) as f:
      height = int(next(f))
      keys = next(f)
      data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
  ```
- building of the `figure` dictionary can be made more efficient using the [`grouper` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

  ```
  def grouper(iterable, n):
      "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
      # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G"
      args = [iter(iterable)] * n
      return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue='')


  def parse_ascii_art_configuration(filename='C://Programs//Python35//Lib//asciiart.txt'):
      with open(filename) as f:
          height = int(next(f))
          keys = next(f)
          data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

      figures = {
          character: list(group)
          for character, group in zip(keys, grouper(data, height))
      }
      ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION.update(figures)
  ```
- now that we use `zip_longest` to concatenate ascii-art letters, you can simplify handling missing symbols by turning `ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION` into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

  ```
  ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION = defaultdict(list)


  def asciiart(text):
      if not ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION:
          parse_ascii_art_configuration()

      return '\n'.join(
                '\n'.join(
                    ' '.join(row)
                    for row in zip_longest(
                        (ASCII_ART_CONFIGURATION[x] for x in line_of_text),
                        fillvalue=''))
                for line_of_text in text.lower().splitlines())
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Ways you can improve your code:

- The body of the if should be on a new line to the if.
  Which makes it *much* more readable.
- Dictionary comprehensions are easier to read than `dict(map())`.
  Incase you didn't know Pythons [BDFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) Guido Van Rossum has [had plans to remove `lambda`, `reduce`, `filter` and `map` from Python](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).
  And so I can't encourage the use of `map` or `lambda`, even if they're still in Python3.
- Your comprehensions are hard to read.
  Don't put them all on one line!
  Spread them out.
  Take:

  > ```
  > art = '\n'.join(['\n'.join([' '.join([figures[x][i] for x in t.lower() if x in figures]) for i in range(height)]) for t in text.split('\n')])
  > ```

  And:

  ```
  art = '\n'.join([
      '\n'.join([
          ' '.join([
              figures[x][i]
              for x in t.lower()
              if x in figures
          ])
          for i in range(height)
      ])
      for t in text.split('\n')
  ])
  ```

  I can read the second much better than the first.
  I also don't know anyone that would object to this.
- I find assigning to a variable to then return it quite redundant.

Ways you could improve your design:

- I find the creation of figures to be quite hard to read.
  What you're doing is making a dictionary of `data` in groups/chunks of `height`.
  Instead of what you're doing now, you could instead use the [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for `grouper`. And `zip` the result with the `keys`.
- Your could add a check to see if the data is divisible by the height.
  This is a basic check to see if the data is actually correct.
  As when I was checking my changes, I didn't use a raw multi-line string.
  Which this check would warn about.
- You can merge the outer two `'\n'.join` comprehensions into one.
  This is kind of hard to explain, but since you're making a list of list of strings.
  And you're performing the `'\n'.join` on both the list of string, and the list of list of strings.
  To get a string, you can just do it on a list of strings.

This can result in something like:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def asciiart(text, conf=default_conf):
    if isinstance(conf, str):
        conf = conf.split('\n')
    height, keys, data = int(conf[0]), conf[1], conf[2:]
    if len(data) % height:
        raise ValueError("Config's data is not divisable by it's height.")
    figures = dict(zip(keys, grouper(data, height)))
    return '\n'.join([
        ' '.join([
            figures[x][i]
            for x in t.lower()
            if x in figures
        ])
        for t in text.split('\n')
        for i in range(height)
    ])
```