# Source formatting of Markdown Table

Tags: python, beginner, markdown

I use [MultiMarkdown](https://rawgit.com/fletcher/human-markdown-reference/master/index.html) tables more than I thought I ever would. In my `.md` files, I would like the *source* table code to be neat, evenly spaced, and resemble (in an alignment sense) the final `HTML` rendered table.

### Solution

Select the *source* of the table, press a hotkey on my computer, replace the untidy table with the tidy table.

### Notes:

- This script (macro?) is for my own use; I will always write the *source* table the same way
- The script is written for Python 2.7
- I use a Mac app that allows me to assign a hot key to an action (e.g. a script), and the following seems to work with that at the moment!

#### Example

I write something like the following:

```
| Header 1 | Header 2 | ... | Header m |  
| :--- | :--: | :--: | --: |  
| $a_{11}$ | $a_{12}$ | ... | $a_{1m}$ |  
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  
| $a_{n1}$ | $a_{n2}$ | ... | $a_{nm} |
```

select it, press my hot key, and it is replaced by something like this (in the source):

```
| Header 1 | Header 2 | ...  | Header m |
| :---     |   :--:   | :--: |      --: |
| $a_{11}$ | $a_{12}$ | ...  | $a_{1m}$ |
| ...      |   ...    | ...  |      ... |
| $a_{n1}$ | $a_{n2}$ | ...  | $a_{nm}$ |
```

As mentioned, the script seems to work.

How can I improve the script?

I would really appreciate some criticism of the script I've written. I am not a coder, but try on occasion to write little tool type things like this.

### The Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""MMD Table Formatter.

Silly script that takes a MMD table as a 
string and returns a tidied version of the table
"""

import sys
import StringIO

query = sys.argv[1]

# For "cleaned" table entries:
rows = []

# This NEEDS TO BE CLOSED AFTER!!
s_obj = StringIO.StringIO(query)
# Clean the entries:
for line in s_obj:
    l = line.split('|')
    rows.append([entry.strip() for entry in l])`enter code here`
# CLOSE
s_obj.close()

# Max length of each "entry" is what we'll use
# to evenly space "columns" in the final table
cols = zip(*rows)
col_widths = []
for columns in cols:
    row_widths = map(lambda x: len(x), columns)
    col_widths.append(max(row_widths))

# Let's align entries as per intended formatting.
# Second line of input string contains alignment commmands:
# ":---"    left aligned
# "---:"    right aligned
# ":--:"    centered (also accepts "---")
alignment = []
for r in rows[1]:
    if r.startswith(":") and not r.endswith(":"):
        alignment.append("lalign")
    elif r.endswith(":") and not r.startswith(":"):
        alignment.append("ralign")
    else:
        alignment.append("centered")

# Prepare for output string:
out = []
for row in rows:
    for entry_and_width in zip(row, col_widths, alignment):
        if entry_and_width[1] == 0:
            continue
        if entry_and_width[2] == "centered":
            outstring = "| " + entry_and_width[0].center(entry_and_width[1]) + ' '
            out.append(outstring)
        if entry_and_width[2] == "lalign":
            outstring = "| " + entry_and_width[0].ljust(entry_and_width[1]) + ' '
            out.append(outstring)
        if entry_and_width[2] == "ralign":
            outstring = "| " + entry_and_width[0].rjust(entry_and_width[1]) + ' '
            out.append(outstring)
    out.append("|\n")

query = "".join(out)

sys.stdout.write(query)
```

Comment: Note that [a similar question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144755/python-ascii-art-table) was asked a few days ago. You might get some insights there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no need for the `StringIO` (?).
You can just use `query.split('\n')`. Regardless, that for loop can be condensed into a list comprehension:

```
rows = [[el.strip() for el in row.split('|')] for row in query.splitlines()]
```

If the `StringIO` is really needed, I would use `with..as`:

```
with StringIO.StringIO(query) as s_obj:
    rows = [[el.strip() for el in row.split('|')] for row in s_obj]
```

For the column widths you can use that `len` is already a function, so there is no need for `lambda x: len(x)`. This way you can also inline all of it into one list comprehension:

```
col_widths = [max(map(len, column)) for column in zip(*rows)]
```

For the alignments, I would define a function that returns the alignment, given the content of a cell. First I had this function return your strings. But then I realized that you are already using `entry.ljust` further down. I then changed it to return the function to use here. Note that `str.ljust("ab", 2)` and `"ab".ljust(2)` are equivalent, so later we just call `align(entry, width)`.

```
def get_alignment(cell):
    """"
    :---"    left aligned
    "---:"    right aligned
    ":--:"    centered (also accepts "---"), default
    """
    if cell.startswith(":") and not cell.endswith(":"):
        return str.ljust
    elif cell.endswith(":") and not cell.startswith(":"):
        return str.rjust
    return str.center
```

To get all alignments, we just use `map` again:

```
alignments = map(get_alignment, rows[1])
```

Finally, the output part. Since you already build a nice tuple with `zip`, you should use tuple unpacking to give the element readable names. `entry_and_widths` is a confusing name, especially since it also contains the alignments!

Here we can now get rid of most of your code, since it boils down to:

```
entry = align(entry, width)
out.append("| {} ".format(entry)
```

Here I used `str.format` to make it a bit easier and avoid the costly string addition. Note that we could also use `str.format` to do the adjusting for us (using e.g. `"{>2}".format(entry)` instead of `"{}".format(str.rjust(entry, 2))`, but that would mean nesting formats, which starts to get ugly very quickly.

I also use the fact that `0` compares to `False` to make the code skipping a column if it is empty shorter.

```
out = []
for row in rows:
    for entry, width, align in zip(row, col_widths, alignments):
        if not width:
            continue
        out.append("| {} ".format(align(entry, width)))
    out.append("|\n")
query = "".join(out)
```

---

**Final code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""MMD Table Formatter.

Silly script that takes a MMD table as a
string and returns a tidied version of the table
"""
import sys


def get_alignment(cell):
    """"
    :---"    left aligned
    "---:"    right aligned
    ":--:"    centered (also accepts "---"), default
    """
    if cell.startswith(":") and not cell.endswith(":"):
        return str.ljust
    elif cell.endswith(":") and not cell.startswith(":"):
        return str.rjust
    return str.center

query = sys.argv[1]

# For "cleaned" table entries:
rows = [[el.strip() for el in row.split('|')] for row in query.splitlines()]

# Max length of each "entry" is what we'll use
# to evenly space "columns" in the final table
col_widths = [max(map(len, column)) for column in zip(*rows)]

# Let's align entries as per intended formatting.
# Second line of input string contains alignment commmands:
alignments = map(get_alignment, rows[1])

# Prepare for output string:
out = []
for row in rows:
    for entry, width, align in zip(row, col_widths, alignments):
        if not width:
            continue
        out.append("| {} ".format(align(entry, width)))
    out.append("|\n")

query = "".join(out)

sys.stdout.write(query)
```

Comment: You should use `query.splitlines()` rather than `query.split('\n')`. Applied to `'test string\n'` the former yield `['test string']` whereas the latter yield `['test string', '']` which is not that convenient to work with.

Comment: Returning `str.ljust` et al., was exactly what I was looking for, and unaware I could do; so cheers. Thanks for reminding me of `map` too :) @MathiasEttinger Originally I had used `splitlines()` but opted for `StringIO` for speed - no idea if this is justified.

Comment: @css As a wild gues I would say its not justified. Unless you had performances issues, ran a profiler and saw that the bottleneck was `splitlines`.

Answer (score 1):

To complete on [@Graipher's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145294/84718), I would simplify the formating of the rows using list-comprehensions/generator expressions rather than building a list to feed into `join`:

```
query = '\n'.join(
    '| {} |'.format(  # Build a row composed of an inner part between delimiters
        ' | '.join(align(entry, width)
                   for entry, width, align in zip(row, col_widths, alignments)))
    for row in rows)
```